# My RegExp test is failing on 2nd iteration

Tags: javascript

i have a code that i want to convert to html entities [ &, <, >, ",' ] however, i am failing with these two <>, on the debugger, the test becomes false, if i switch them, the first one works? the code is same with ",' , so why does <> don't work?

```
function convertHTML(str) {
  // &colon;&rpar;
  var a = /[&]/ig;
  var b = /[><><<>><]/ig;
  var c = /["']/ig;
  var e = str.split('');
  var t = [];

  function qw(item) {
    return (item == '>') ? '&gt;' : '&lt;';
  }

  function fg(item) {
    return (item == '"') ? '&quot;' : '&apos;';
  }

  for (var x = 0; x < e.length; x++) {
    var cv = e[x];
    if (a.test(cv)) {
      cv = '&amp;';
      t.push(cv);
    } else if (b.test(cv)) {
      var er = qw(cv); // invoke function, the error is here, on the second iteration
      t.push(er);
    } else if (c.test(cv)) {
      var df = fg(cv);
      t.push(df);
    } else {
      t.push(cv);
    }
  }
  return t.join('');
}
convertHTML("><");
```

Comment: Why do you have the "g" flag on your regular expressions? Taking it away will make a difference.

Comment: thanks, it fixed, i think i have to reread more docs.. i was used to it,  :/